# Create dynamic key in object JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I want to create a dynamic key in a js object. I know I can create it like this but id doesn't fullfil my requirements

```
return {
  [dynamicKey]: value
}
```

But the problem is I want something like this

```
return {
  [dynamicKey]_id: value
}
```

but it doesn't let me, I tried concatenating but it didn't work.

```
return {
  [dynamicKey] + '_id': value
}
```

I've also searched online for a solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: `[dinamicKey + '_id']: value` - the whole expression must be inside the square brackets.

Comment: Solved my problems, thx!

Answer (score 4):

you need to put your `_id` string inside of the square brackets or as part of the `dinamicKey` var.

```
return {
  [dinamicKey + '_id']: value
}
```

```
dinamicKey += '_id';
return {
  [dinamicKey]: value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any expression in the square braces will be executed just like a normal expression.
So how about this:

```
return {
    [dinamicKey + '_id']: value
}
```